# Flutter change TextField "lableStyle" on error

Tags: flutter

I have a custom [TextFormField] and I want the label style to become red when there is an error. just like border. but in [TextFormField] there is not any parameter for error label style.

how can I manage this? can you provide me an example code? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Can you include the code-snippet that will reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
InputDecoration(
    errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
     borderSide: BorderSide(color:redColor),
    ),
    focusedErrorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
     borderSide: BorderSide(color: redColor),
    ),
    errorStyle: const TextStyle(
      height: 0.5,
      color: redColor,
    ),
)
```